# Apache 2.4.4 WAMP VHosts error

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I had created two VirtualHosts earlier namely [localhost] and "phpsite". Yesterday I renamed "phpsite" as "phppages" and added one more virtual host named "techsupport.com". I use port 8088 on my Apache server. But now I am able to use [localhost]:8088 and phpsite:8088 though there's no virtual host named "phpsite" and if I go for techsupport.com:8088 I get nothing.

Here's my vhost content:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
#    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
#    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
#    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
#    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
#    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
#</VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
#    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
#    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
#    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
#    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
#</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8088>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost.com
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8088>
     DocumentRoot "e:/techsupport"
     ServerName techsupport.com
     ServerAlias www.techsupport.com
     ErrorLog "logs/techsupport-error.log"
     CustomLog "logs/techsupport-access.log" common
     <Directory "e:/TechSupport">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Order Deny,Allow
         Deny from all
         Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8088>
    DocumentRoot "e:/phppages"
    ServerName phppages
    ServerAlias www.phppages.com
    ErrorLog "logs/phppages-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/phppages-access.log" common
    <Directory "e:/PHPPages">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache's error log shows this:

```
[Sun Aug 25 12:50:06.646882 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7936:tid 500] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 25 12:50:06.646882 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7936:tid 500] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Sun Aug 25 12:50:06.646882 2013] [core:notice] [pid 7936:tid 500] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Sun Aug 25 12:50:06.647883 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7936:tid 500] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 912
[Sun Aug 25 12:50:07.216263 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 912:tid 384] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sun Aug 25 12:51:15.409867 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7936:tid 500] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun Aug 25 12:51:17.411205 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 912:tid 384] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun Aug 25 12:51:17.433218 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7936:tid 500] AH00430: Parent: Child process 912 exited successfully.
[Sun Aug 25 12:51:30.206760 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11396:tid 204] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 25 12:51:30.207763 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11396:tid 204] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Sun Aug 25 12:51:30.207763 2013] [core:notice] [pid 11396:tid 204] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Sun Aug 25 12:51:30.208763 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11396:tid 204] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4808
[Sun Aug 25 12:51:30.670070 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4808:tid 384] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sun Aug 25 13:25:30.406049 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11396:tid 204] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun Aug 25 13:25:32.406924 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4808:tid 384] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun Aug 25 13:25:32.423935 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11396:tid 204] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4808 exited successfully.
[Sun Aug 25 13:28:38.706114 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10328:tid 516] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 25 13:28:38.706114 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10328:tid 516] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Sun Aug 25 13:28:38.706114 2013] [core:notice] [pid 10328:tid 516] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Sun Aug 25 13:28:38.708114 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10328:tid 516] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4716
[Sun Aug 25 13:28:39.170423 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4716:tid 380] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sun Aug 25 13:33:14.347584 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10328:tid 516] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun Aug 25 13:33:16.349839 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4716:tid 380] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun Aug 25 13:33:16.369232 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10328:tid 516] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4716 exited successfully.
[Sun Aug 25 13:33:18.445939 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7048:tid 464] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 25 13:33:18.445939 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7048:tid 464] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Sun Aug 25 13:33:18.445939 2013] [core:notice] [pid 7048:tid 464] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Sun Aug 25 13:33:18.446940 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7048:tid 464] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2556
[Sun Aug 25 13:33:18.801179 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2556:tid 324] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sun Aug 25 13:35:23.175992 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7048:tid 464] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun Aug 25 13:35:25.178255 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2556:tid 324] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun Aug 25 13:35:25.197268 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7048:tid 464] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2556 exited successfully.
[Sun Aug 25 13:35:28.224795 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10616:tid 504] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 25 13:35:28.224795 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10616:tid 504] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Sun Aug 25 13:35:28.224795 2013] [core:notice] [pid 10616:tid 504] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Sun Aug 25 13:35:28.225792 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10616:tid 504] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4012
[Sun Aug 25 13:35:28.599042 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4012:tid 324] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sun Aug 25 13:43:03.326392 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10616:tid 504] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun Aug 25 13:43:07.389104 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4012:tid 324] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun Aug 25 13:43:07.404736 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10616:tid 504] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4012 exited successfully.
[Sun Aug 25 13:45:26.908312 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4788:tid 504] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 25 13:45:26.970818 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4788:tid 504] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Sun Aug 25 13:45:26.970818 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4788:tid 504] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Sun Aug 25 13:45:26.970818 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4788:tid 504] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5084
[Sun Aug 25 13:45:27.517719 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5084:tid 384] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

In httpd.cnf file:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8088
```

(Earlier it was just Listen 8088)

And

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

is uncommented as it should be.

I am helpless right now and have already spent 2 days on it. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had created two VirtualHosts earlier namely [localhost] and "phpsite". Yesterday I renamed "phpsite" as "phppages" and added one more virtual host named "techsupport.com". I use port 8088 on my Apache server. But now I am able to use [localhost]:8088 and phpsite:8088 though there's no virtual host named "phpsite" and if I go for techsupport.com:8088 I get nothing.

The only reason that "phppages" is not working and "phpsite" is working could be because you have a DNS entry or an entry in the host file for "phpsite" and not for "phppages".  To debug this I would start by pinging them.

```
ping phppages

ping phpsite
```

While we're at the name resolution topic, your `techsupport.com:8088` is not going to work because `techsupport.com` gets resolved to external site.  If they don't have port 8088 open to the public, you simply won't be able to navigate to that site on that port.  However, if they did then you would have been able to browse their pages not yours.

I'm not sure how WAMP manages host names, but the first thing to check is your DNS Server if you have one, otherwise check `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

To make `phppages` work add the following lines to your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1    phppages    www.phppages.com

# Similarly for techsupport.com and www.techsupport.com
127.0.0.1    techsupport.com    www.techsupport.com
```

After this your phppages and techsupport urls should work.

**Caution:** Adding public URLs to your hosts file might cause confusions in future when/if you removed that virtual host from `httpd-vhosts.conf` and forget to remove corresponding host name from the host file, in which case these public URLs will not be reachable to the correct destination.  So, it is not recommended to use public host names for your virtual hosts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @vinod. I just forgot to add new websites entries into the hosts file at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\. Thank you